# Why we cannot apply pole placement for the following system?

Tags: control-theory

$$ \begin{cases} 
\dot{x}=\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \\ \end{pmatrix} x+\begin{pmatrix} 2  \\ 2 \\ \end{pmatrix} u  \\  y=Cx 
\end{cases} $$

How can I show that if $p_1 \neq -2$ and $p_2 \neq -2$, then it is impossible to apply pole placement for the above system by using
$$det(sI-A-BK)=0.$$

After taking the determination I got the following equation.
$$(s+2)(s+2-2k_1-2k_2)=0$$

Where $K=(k_1,k_2)$

Comment: After finding the determination I don't understand how to proceed.

Comment: You have made a mistake in your calculations. The correct value of the determinant is $(s+2)(s+2-2k_1-2k_2)$. This explains why you cannot assign both poles in points different from $-2$. At least one pole always remains in $-2$ after state feedback.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I show that it is impossible to apply pole placement ? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Pole placement means that you can place arbitrarily the poles of the closed-loop system $A+BK$ by suitably selecting $K$. In your example, this is not possible because, as you can see from the above determinant one pole is stuck in $-2$ for all values of $k_1,k_2$.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: the system is not completely controllable, and feedback does not alter controllability.

Answer (score 0):

You can also notice that the system is not controllable. Controllability is necessary as well as sufficient for placement of poles in arbitrary locations.